# how to achieve following View - UI in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

The picture shown below is the profile fragment.
I want to achieve this, but not sure whats the name of this view and how can i achieve that.

Transition : When activity opens its 1 image.
and when you slide down lower part or picture, it has map view behind.
which is stuck behind. You can lower or up the lower part of activity.

Any tutorial and information on this? 
Thank you.

[Youtube Video showing what exactly it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=df1VdBImcDE&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: you can make it using frame layout and keep background color of above part transparent. For transitions you can Umano sliding panel library

Comment: I had sense of using `FrameLayout` , but what about the lower part? how can i set the round Image on that Edge. And also that part slides down and up.

Comment: yes for that use another library namely rounded imageview with border and for sliding I already told you

Answer (score 1):

The sliding view in the foreground is called a `BottomSheet`. It was recently added to Android Support Library in v23. You can check the blog post [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) for usage and more info. There are also a couple of open source libraries which have implementations of this View.

For the circular image you can use this library: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: This is helpful, yet i need more answers! Thank you i appreciate this :) up one for blog link. thanks